# Smarty TPL array inside variable?

Tags: php, smarty

My problem, Exapmle:

```
$a = array(); <- 1 mysql row
$id1 = 0; $id2 = 0;
$smarty->assign("a",$a);
$smarty->assign("id1",$id1);
$smarty->assign("id2",$id2);
```

---

Solution in PHP:

```
if($a['column_'.$id1.'_'.$id2]==0){echo"ok";}else{echo"no";}
```

Smarty TPL?
I tried:

```
{if $a.column_'.$id1.'_'.$id2 == 0}{/if}
```

Fatal error (:
I don't find any help, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first recourse should be to try to restructure your data - whether in PHP or in Smarty, using a compound key to represent multiple dimensions of data like that tends to get messy fast. PHP makes working with multi-dimensional arrays incredibly easy, so it's a shame not to use that power.

You could loop over your data and produce a new structure with something like this:

```
$better_structured_array = [];
foreach ( $awkward_raw_array as $old_key => $item_value ) {
    list($first_key, $second_key, $third_key) = explode('_', $old_key);
    $better_structured_array[$first_key][$second_key][$third_key] = $item_value;
}
```

Then your Smarty would be easy:

```
{if $a.column[$id1][$id2] == 0}{/if}
```

If you really can't do that for some reason, the trick is to build the key into a variable first, then use it as a key access:

```
{assign name=ugly_array_key value='column_'|cat:$id1|cat:'_'|cat:$id2}
{if $a[$ugly_array_key] == 0}{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you this answer, but my problem is different. Sorry my bad English, I try to summarize. I have three array. 

For example: $selects, $options, $saved_data. 
{foreach from=$selects item=i}
<select name="select_{$i.input_ID}">
{foreach from=$options item=o}
{if $o.option_input_ID eq $i.input_ID}
<option value="select_{$i.input_ID}_{$o.option_ID}" >{$o.label}</option>
{/if}{/foreach}{/foreach}

Comment: SO! If the user save something, I should be displayed. ->> <option value="select_{$i.input_ai}_{$o.option_ai}" {if $saved_data.select_{$i.input_ID}_{$o.option_ID} == 'select_'.{$i.input_ai}_{$o.option_ai}} selected="selected"{/if}>{$o.label}</option>

Comment: This is a problem. The {if ...} selected="selected"{/if}

Comment: @WOLFNeT I don't see how that is different from the example you already gave. Build the key with `{assign name=my_key value='select_'|cat:$i.input_ID|cat:'_'|cat:$o.option_ID}`  and replace `$saved_data.select_{$i.input_ID}_{$o.option_ID}` with `$saved_data[$my_key]`. Or restructure the `$saved_data` array, as described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to write your business logic in templates?

Smarty templates are developed so that developers (business logic) and designers (presentation) can work independently.

So that business logic and presentation logic are kept apart from each other.

Its always better to evaluate all your expressions in PHP and pass output to templates.

There, variables can be printed.

Comment: Yup i know, but now it is inevitable. I use dynamic FORM SELECT generation in TPL. If this {IF} true, then selected a row. Wee need to find an option! :)

Comment: Can't it be handled through AJAX if dynamic forms?

Comment: Hmm maybe yes. But in this cause I need send any information to ajax script... and you know in one page I have many input, select, checkbox etc.., and these items are automatically generated... I don't want to use everywhere ajax. :D

Comment: I don't really see this as business logic. The view is deciding to access a particular element of the data. This example is obviously heavily simplified, but there are plenty of scenarios where the view wants to cross-reference multiple variables provided by the business logic. What's more, this doesn't really answer the question, and feels more like a comment to me.